# how do i integrate jboss with eclipse to run debug process

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, struts

hey guys please help me to find a way out for debugging my application on eclipse helios.
i have to configure jboss and debug my application

please guide me

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you deploy your application through eclipse? If you do, then all you need to do is add breakpoints in the code, deploy and start jboss in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying your application via Eclipse, then heldt's comment above is enough for you. However, if you're not you can make use of the [remote debugging capabilities built-in to the Java platform](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/).

1. Import your project into Eclipse
2. Start JBoss in debug mode (make note of the port being used, it's usually 8787) by editing the configurations to look like the following:

   ```
   set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
   ```
3. Use the debugger in Eclipse to connect to the server process on the debug port. On my setup of Eclipse 3.5, I need to go to  `Run > Debug Configurations`, select `Remote Java Application` from the sidebar, create a new configuration and set the appropriate connection parameters.

Here are are links to a few tutorials that explain this process in more detail:

- http://blog.mangar.com.br/?p=53
- http://www.jacoozi.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=119&Itemid=134
- http://onjava.com/onjava/2005/08/31/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html
- http://java.sys-con.com/node/44918